# mdpi hdpi xhdpi what is the rule of resolution?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

In iOS when creating image set I need to set image with resolution (x,y), (2x,2y), (3x, 3y). Is something similar rule for Android for mdpi hdpi xhdpi?

I want to use pixel precise image for different size classes in Android.

Which setting I need to select when adding `Image Asset`? I need this images to arbitrary place in the app as `ImageView`.

[image]

Comment: you might wanna try this [android.dev support different densities](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Comment: I guess you are confusing `resolution` with `density`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(0.75x) for low-density
(1.0x baseline) for medium-density
(1.5x) for high-density
(2.0x) for extra-high-density
(3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
(4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density
```

from [Official Documentetion](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Do you know which setting I need when adding `Image Asset`?

Comment: Those icons has different purposes and size. Take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html) manual.

Answer (score 3):

**Pixel Densities**

mdpi (Baseline):    160 dpi 1×

hdpi:   240 dpi 1.5×

xhdpi:  320 dpi 2×

xxhdpi: 480 dpi 3×

xxxhdpi:    640 dpi 4×

**Launcher icons**

48 × 48 (mdpi)

72 × 72 (hdpi)

96 × 96 (xhdpi)

144 × 144 (xxhdpi)

192 × 192 (xxxhdpi)

512 × 512 (Google Play store)

**Action bar, Dialog & Tab icons**

24 × 24 area in 32 × 32 (mdpi)

36 × 36 area in 48 × 48 (hdpi)

48 × 48 area in 64 × 64 (xhdpi)

72 × 72 area in 96 × 96 (xxhdpi)

96 × 96 area in 128 × 128 (xxxhdpi)

**Small Contextual Icons**

16 × 16 (mdpi)

24 × 24 (hdpi)

32 × 32 (xhdpi)

48 × 48 (xxhdpi)

64 × 64 (xxxhdpi)

**Notification icons**

22 × 22 area in 24 × 24 (mdpi)

33 × 33 area in 36 × 36 (hdpi)

44 × 44 area in 48 × 48 (xhdpi)

66 × 66 area in 72 × 72 (xxhdpi)

88 × 88 area in 96 × 96 (xxxhdpi)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the scaling factors for various device densities

```
(0.75x) for low-density
(1.0x baseline) for medium-density
(1.5x) for high-density
(2.0x) for extra-high-density
(3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
(4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me specify more.

In the Android There are three Type of Image(icon) to use in the Android App.

for the density purpose @Andriy Omelchenko is right.

But you have to Create this way..

if the Image is (Action Bar and Tab icon)

```
mdpi = 32 * 32
hdpi = 48 * 48
xhdpi = 64 * 64
xxhdpi = 96 * 96
```

if the Image(Notification Icon)

```
mdpi = 25 * 25
hdpi = 38 * 38
xhdpi = 50 * 50
xxhdpi = 75 * 75
```

if the Image(Launcher Icon)

```
mdpi = 48 * 48
hdpi = 72 * 72
xhdpi = 96 * 96
xxhdpi = 144 * 144
xxxhdpi = 196 * 196
```

Comment: What if I need image for arbitrary `ImageView`? How to create `Image Asset`? Which setting I need?

Comment: @János as you are using is for Icon only. for the Image you have to 9 patch Image generator for more detail visit this : https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Comment: But 9 patch is for buttons where the width is changing based on the content, text isn't it?  But in my case I have just an image with `44dp x 44dp`.

Comment: @János if you have fix size then create that only size image and put it on drawable folder so that it can access in all device.

Comment: But this is not pixel precise design.